# Visual Studio 2015 / Xamarin, Debug not working: an error occurred while executing MTouch

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to get an answer on here before uninstalling this software and developing straight on Mac after spending 4 hours trying to figure this out. I just installed all these programs on both machines (VS15/Xamarin on Windows 10, Xcode/Xamarin on iMac, both on the same network). Mac Agent is connected, I have a Developer account on XCode, a device linked to my account, everything looks fine.

When I create a basic app (I don't even add a line of code, just a blank single view app) on XCode (iMac) and launch the simulator, it works just fine. I get the view of the device etc... When I do the same on my Windows machine, I can't debug. I get the error "The app could not be launched on 'iPhone SE iOS 10.2'. An error occurred while executing MTouch."

I looked all over the place searching for a solution. I removed the Entitlements.plist file, I also checked for updates on everything (as some suggested on StackOverflow). Nothing.

So I tried an Android app to see if that works and no issue there. I get the device I pick, shows a black screen because the app is empty, as expected.

If anyone can guide me before I uninstall this whole thing and code directly on a Mac, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Did you check the simulator logs?

Comment: I did. No error reported on the Mac

Answer (score 1):

Restarting Visual Studio and cleaning iOS project worked for me.